zooming and mouse click with JFrame and AffineTransform
I'm having a issue with mouse click being tied to JFrame location while a BufferedImage is being displayed and setting the location of the mouse click relative to the scaling of a zoom.
(code is from this forum: Zooming in and zooming out within a panel)
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    if (zoomer) {
        AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
        double xRel = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getX() - getLocationOnScreen().getX();
        double yRel = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getY() - getLocationOnScreen().getY();
        double zoomDiv = zoomFactor / prevZoomFactor;
        xOffset = (zoomDiv) * (xOffset) + (1 - zoomDiv) * xRel;
        yOffset = (zoomDiv) * (yOffset) + (1 - zoomDiv) * yRel;
        at.translate(xOffset, yOffset);
        at.scale(zoomFactor, zoomFactor);
        totalZoom *=zoomFactor;
        prevZoomFactor = zoomFactor;
        g2.transform(at);
        zoomer = false;
    }
    if (dragger) {
        AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
        at.translate(xOffset + xDiff, yOffset + yDiff);
        at.scale(zoomFactor, zoomFactor);
        g2.transform(at);
        if (released) {
            xOffset += xDiff;
            yOffset += yDiff;
            dragger = false;
        }
    }
}

I tried to change the mouse click location via using math but I am struggling with doing it correctly.
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
    double x = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getX() - getLocationOnScreen().getX();
    double y = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getY() - getLocationOnScreen().getY();

    try {
        CommandFromClient clientSubmission= new CommandFromClient(CommandFromClient.GETBOARD);
        os.writeObject(clientSubmission);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    System.out.println("x: " + getLocationOnScreen().getX()/zoomFactor + "y: " + getLocationOnScreen().getY()/zoomFactor);

    Point clicked = new Point((int)((me.getPoint().x*10-x)),(int)((me.getPoint().y*10-y)));
    System.out.println(1f/zoomFactor);
    System.out.println("CLICK DETECTED: " + clicked);
    for(int i = yellow.size()-1;i>=0;i--) {
        Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(yellow.get(i).getX(),yellow.get(i).getY(),yellow.get(i).getImg().getWidth(),yellow.get(i).getImg().getHeight());
        System.out.print("checks");
        if(bounds.contains(clicked)){
            System.out.print("collided");
            System.out.print(yellow.get(i));
            break;
        }
    }
}


Hello user, I don't know the usage scenario, but what I usually do to avoid processing overloads, is to create an array with an image in all the expected sizes, this consumes "quite a few" resources during the start of the application, but makes it go "finer" during its use.

If you were looking for the location of a mouse click that has been transformed by the same series of affine transformations, then you can save the current affine transformation that you are applying to your image and then apply that to the point. To do this, create an AffineTransformation variable within your panel class,
private AffineTransform currentTransform = new AffineTransform();

then your paint method would be updated to save the affine transformation to this variable. The method would look as follows, with the updated bits commented:
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    //if zoomer or dragger is true, this means that a new affine transformation is going to be made, so the currentTransform is reset
    if (zoomer || dragger) {
        currentTransform = new AffineTransform();
    }
    //if neither zoomer or dragger is true, then the graphics object will have no affine transformation to apply to the shapes on screen, so it will temporarily reset the screen
    //this line counteracts that, applying the current transformation to the shapes so they maintain their location on screen
    else {
        g2d.transform(currentTransform);
    }
    if (zoomer) {
        AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
        
        double xRel = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getX() - getLocationOnScreen().getX();
        double yRel = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getY() - getLocationOnScreen().getY();
        
        double zoomDiv = zoomFactor / prevZoomFactor;
        
        xOffset = (zoomDiv) * (xOffset) + (1 - zoomDiv) * xRel;
        yOffset = (zoomDiv) * (yOffset) + (1 - zoomDiv) * yRel;
        
        at.translate(xOffset, yOffset);
        at.scale(zoomFactor, zoomFactor);
        prevZoomFactor = zoomFactor;
        currentTransform.concatenate(at);//adds the calculated zoom transformation to the current transformation
        g2d.transform(at);
        zoomer = false;
    }
    
    if (dragger) {
        AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
        at.translate(xOffset + xDiff, yOffset + yDiff);
        at.scale(zoomFactor, zoomFactor);
        currentTransform.concatenate(at);//adds the dragger transformation so the current transformation is now a combination of the zoom and drag transformation
        g2d.transform(at);

        if (released) {
            xOffset += xDiff;
            yOffset += yDiff;
            dragger = false;
        }

    }

    g2d.fillRect(0,0,200,200);
    
    g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
}

Finally, we can apply this saved affine transformation to the mouse's point when a click occurs:
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
    Point2D mousePoint = currentTransform.transform(me.getPoint(), null);
    System.out.println(mousePoint);
    repaint();
}

Let me know if this was what you were looking for, your wording was a bit confusing to me, but I think I understood it.

I found a solution to my problem via applying a point at the upper and lower bounds and transforming it by the AT.
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);


    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setPaint(Color.red);
    zero = new Point(0,0);
    max = new Point(10000,10000);
    Point2D test2 = new Point(0,0);
    if (zoomer) {
        AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();

        double xRel = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getX() - getLocationOnScreen().getX();
        double yRel = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getY() - getLocationOnScreen().getY();

        double zoomDiv = zoomFactor / prevZoomFactor;

        xOffset = (zoomDiv) * (xOffset) + (1 - zoomDiv) * xRel;
        yOffset = (zoomDiv) * (yOffset) + (1 - zoomDiv) * yRel;

        at.translate(xOffset, yOffset);
        at.scale(zoomFactor, zoomFactor);
        totalZoom *=zoomFactor;
        prevZoomFactor = zoomFactor;
        g2.transform(at);
        zero = at.transform(zero,null);
        max = at.transform(max,null);
        zoomer = false;
    }

    if (dragger) {
        AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
        at.scale(zoomFactor, zoomFactor);
        g2.transform(at);
        zero = at.transform(zero,null);
        max = at.transform(max,null);

        if (released) {
            xOffset += xDiff;
            yOffset += yDiff;
            dragger = false;
        }

    }

and the mouse listener
@Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
    double x = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getX() - getLocationOnScreen().getX();
    double y = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getY() - getLocationOnScreen().getY();

    double scaleX = 10000/(max.getX()-zero.getX());
    double scaleY = 10000/(max.getY()-zero.getY());
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Scale x; "+ scaleX + " Scale y; "+scaleY);

    double finX = (x-zero.getX())*scaleX;
    double finY = (y-zero.getY())*scaleY;

    //System.out.println(zoomFactor);
    System.out.println("CLICK DETECTED: x final " + finX + "y final " + finY);

    Point2D playerClick = new Point((int)finX,(int)finY);

    //NO TOUCHY
    boolean isFound = false;
    for(int i = gd.purpleCenterCards.length-1;i>=0 && !isFound;i--) {
        Rectangle bounds = null;
        try {
            bounds = new Rectangle(gd.purpleCenterCards[i].getX(), gd.purpleCenterCards[i].getY(), (int)(ImageIO.read(new File(gd.purpleCenterCards[i].fileName)).getWidth()*scaleX), (int)(ImageIO.read(new File(gd.purpleCenterCards[i].fileName)).getHeight()*scaleX));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        System.out.print("checks");
        if(bounds.contains(playerClick)){
            System.out.print("collided");
            System.out.print(gd.purpleCenterCards[i]);
            isFound = true;
        }
    }
    for(int i = gd.yellowCenterCards.length-1;i>=0 && !isFound;i--) {
        Rectangle bounds = null;
        try {
            bounds = new Rectangle(gd.yellowCenterCards[i].getX(), gd.yellowCenterCards[i].getY(), (int)(ImageIO.read(new File(gd.yellowCenterCards[i].fileName)).getWidth()*scaleX), (int)(ImageIO.read(new File(gd.yellowCenterCards[i].fileName)).getHeight()*scaleX));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        System.out.print("checks");
        if(bounds.contains(playerClick)){
            System.out.print("collided");
            System.out.print(gd.yellowCenterCards[i]);
            isFound = true;
        }
    }
    for(int i = players.length-1;i>=0 && !isFound;i--) {
        Rectangle bounds = null;
        try {
            bounds = new Rectangle(players[i].getX(), players[i].getY(), (int)(ImageIO.read(new File(players[i].getPlayer().getCaravan().getIcon())).getWidth()*scaleX), (int)(ImageIO.read(new File(players[i].getPlayer().getCaravan().getIcon())).getHeight()*scaleX));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        System.out.print("checks");
        if(bounds.contains(playerClick)){
            System.out.print("collided");
            System.out.print(gd.yellowCenterCards[i]);
            isFound = true;
        }
    }
    if(!isFound){
        System.out.println("NO CARDS FOUND");
    }
}

I hope this helps out someone later on who has this same problem. Anyways good bye :)
